# Expandable Vertical Bar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[image: Desired effect]
I've this requirement on API level 8+.
Briefly, I've to swipe the gradient bar from left to right (or tap),
to "enlarge" it, adding semi-trasparent effect to content
and some white-text description on it. User should be able
to restore initial situation tapping or swiping back.
Application is in full screen mode.
Is Navigation Drawer Layout the right way to proceed, or a good starting
point? Have you ever implemented something similar? Any library suggestion?
Can I somehow "x-traslate" the navigation drawer widget to be partially visible
at the beginning? I really need help to keep things simple here. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), and inside your menu, put a fragment whose view is a this transparent gradient